# Flutter - How can I add a widget to the border of a Container?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Assuming that I have an ordinary container. How can I add a widget, for example, a Button to the border of my Container?

[Container with a button on border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuFKS.png)

Comment: Có thể dùng stack luôn nha :)

Comment: @darkness tại cái container của mình nó nằm trong expanded á, nên stack thì cái nó sẽ bị lõm 1 miếng bên phải. Mình xài package Badges chỉnh lại xí thấy chạy ngon :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Badges](https://pub.dev/packages/badges) plugin. for example, in your case you can wrap the container with **Badge** and modify the **position** parameter which is a BadgePosition to the exact **bottom** and **right** values.

```
Badge(
      position: BadgePosition.bottomRight(bottom: 0,right: 0),//change this to get the right location
      badgeContent: YourWidgetAtTheBorder(),
      child: YourContainer(),
       
    )
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget to overlap some widgets, then just create first the container (I used a Card just to simulate the elevation and border effect) and after that add the icon, button, etc, by deault it aligns thewidget in the TopLeft corner, I change it to the centerRight, but if you want more control just wrap the widget in an Align or a Positioned widget to move them where you want

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Size size = Size(400, 400);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, children: [
      Card(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0), //half the size the icon so it looks like in the middle of the border
          elevation: 8,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2)
          ),
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: SizedBox.fromSize(
            size: size, child: Center(child: Text('MyText'))
          )
      ),
      Icon(Icons.done, size: 48)
    ]);
  }
}
```

[image]